# Passing data from one Ajax inside another

Tags: jquery

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Kostas/measurementData.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {UserID: <?php echo json_encode($UserID); ?>, MeasurementID: selected},
    success: function (data) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Kostas/measurementData.php",
            type: "POST",
            data2: {UserID: <?php echo json_encode($UserID); ?>, MeasurementID: 2},
            success: function (data, data2) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data2);

            },
            error: function (data) {
               console.log("error 2");
            } 
        });

    },
    error: function (data) {
       console.log("error 1");
    }
});
```

What I want to do is to proccess the data,data2 inside the second function but the console log does not show that the data have been populated. How do I solve this?
UPDATE :
Added the error console.log and it hits on the error 2

**Answer tailored for my code for future references by other people**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Kostas/measurementData.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {UserID: <?php echo json_encode($UserID); ?>, MeasurementID: selected},
    success: function (data) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Kostas/measurementData.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {UserID: <?php echo json_encode($UserID); ?>, MeasurementID: 2},
            success: function (data2) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data2);

            },
            error: function (data2) {
                console.log("error 2");
            }
        });

    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("error 1");
    }
});
```

Comment: there must be a conflict between `data` variables. Rename your second data variable inside `success (data,data2)` to another name.

Comment: @ibubi didn't change anything, still the console shows empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename `data` in second `success`. The first `data` is still in scope and can be accessed in the second `success`

```
$.ajax({
    //.....
    success: function (data) {
        $.ajax({
            //.....
            success: function (data2) {
                console.log(data);// data from first request
                console.log(data2);// data2 from second request

            },
             //.....
        });

    },
    //.....
```

Comment: No still the console displays nothing

Comment: Are error handlers being triggered? Should work fine assuming both requests succeed

Comment: None and the problem isn't that the data can't be populated, if i remove the inside ajax it shows up properly

Comment: Ok so i a console.log in both error clauses and it hits error in the inside ajax, but still can't figure out why

Comment: That's what the error handler is for... to inspect xhr object and tell you why. Also inspect request in browser dev tools network

Comment: Yes it does, trying your example, the way you posted it i assumed it was still data2: .... etc. Edit it and I will select it as an answer

Comment: edit what? The answer is correct and clearly works as per the demo

Comment: Just so there isn't any missunderstanding from someone who sees the answer. But ok

Comment: No idea what you are talking about

Comment: Oh i see what your problem is....you renamed the option `data` to `data2`. That must be `data` as per the docs

Comment: Yes, and cause you didn't correct it on your comment i assumed it was not wrong, that's why it didn't work at first.